# New Safari 7 useragent string

Tags: safari, user-agent

I wouldn't really want to bother you here, but as I don't have a mac I cannot test this.

I made a browser sniffing class (I know it's bad but it works well and is not the point).

This all works fine, however my colleague said there was a bugg on a website I recently did.
All I would like to know / see is if there is a link to any website that has the Safari 7 useragent string documented / raw or if someone could post the Safari 7 UA string here (`$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` in PHP).

I checked for this on google and websites as [useragentstring.com](http://www.useragentstring.com), but cant get the UA from there either.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found it:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9) AppleWebKit/537.71 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Safari/537.71
```