# Safari 8 user agent string // Enabling & Opening Safari console

Tags: safari, user-agent

Hey there SO crew

---

Almost 2 years ago *(1y and about 10mo)* I posted this [Safari 7 user-agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19937837/new-safari-7-useragent-string) here and ever since it's just been standing there doing it's thing so I thought, why don't I take 5min and put this one on there as well since it might be interesting for some to use for purposes other than browser sniffing (even tho I think browser sniffing isn't at all bad if used the right way - the **"eval = evil problem"**).

So my question obviously is: *What is the Safari 8 User agent string?*

As a side-question: *If I am using Safari, how would I find my UA string?*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Q1A: Aaand here it is, our Safari 8+ UA string.

---

`Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_4) AppleWebKit/600.7.12 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0.7 Safari/600.7.12`

"How did I get it?" One might ask.

---

Well this is not exactly difficult when sitting behind a mac with the latest Safari always installed but I do remember how annoyed I was that I couldn't find the Safari 7 UA string **ANYWHERE**.

Anyways, if you're a developer and you're working on a Mac (perhaps a Junior? - like me :D) Here are some simple steps to find the UA of Safari:

#### Q2A: Step 1: Open a webpage

Open Safari first, then open any webpage (e.g. [google.com](https://google.com))

---

#### Q2A: Step 2: Open the console

*short way*

Press <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> to open the 
console.

*long way*

In the top left menu bar hit *Develop* -> *Show Web Inspector*

Don't see the *Develop* menu? Go to *Safari* -> *Preferences (<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>)* -> *Advanced* -> *Check the checkbox where it says **Show Develop menu in menu bar***

---

#### Q2A: Step 3: Navigate to User-Agent

With the **Web Inspector open** go to the *Timelines* menu

[image]

Then go to a random request that was made to the server from the page, I literally chose a random script anywhere under the *resources* pane below the *timelines* pane.

Then look on the right side of the console *(if the console displayed below the page and not next to it.)* and check the **Request Headers** -> *User-Agent*

If the console is displayed next to your browser window, you'll have to look for the icon to the right of the bin icon:

[image]

Clicking the icon will toggle the request information on or off accordingly.

[image]

And there it is, the UA in all of it's glory!

Hope it helps - Sidney Liebrand

Comment: So why is there Mozilla/5.0 in the UA sting if it's Apple and Webkit?

Comment: @cullub this is for legacy reasons since a lot of folks back in the day used to sniff that string and some websites might still sniff it today, UA's contain a lot of lies and deceit :)

Answer (score 3):

Too new to comment on an answer, but there is a much easier and foolproof three-step method for obtaining the user-agent string of Safari on OS X / macOS.

Within Safari:

1. If necessary, show the Develop menu

> Safari > Preferences > Advanced > Show Develop menu in menu bar

2. Develop > User Agent > Other...

> Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/601.6.17
>   (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.1.1 Safari/601.6.17

There is no Step 3 :-)

Comment: Very much true you can do it this way, however I like seeing the request the browser actually makes in case you're using a user agent switcher (not sure if *Develop -> User Agent > Other* menu notices fake UA or general UA changes).

Answer (score 0):

My answer in 2023:

- open DevTools (CMD + Option + I)
- enter this command: `window.navigator.userAgent`

[image: get user agent via dev tools console]